# Spacing letters in a word so that the end result is exactly a given width

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

So my problem is the following.

I can't seem to figure out how to space 6 letters in Illustrator that are 10mm high so that the end result is 80mm wide.

If someone has a solution for this that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would do it.

**Note:** I did this with the assumption that the letters are random and the order doesn't matter. When you're working with an actual word, the steps are the same, just make sure the word is in order before you distribute.

---

#### Start with your 6 letters.

[image: 6 random letters]

Use vertical-align and horizontal distribute to get them in some kind of a working order.
[image: vertical align]
[image: horizontal distribute]
[image: preliminary result]

#### Make a rectangle that is exactly 88mm wide.

You can literally just type in 88mm and Ai will translate that into px for you.
[image: 88mm rectangle]

Put your word inside the box.

#### Align the outermost letters to the right and left edges of the box.

[image: before aligning]
[image: after aligning]
*Accidentally hit horizontal centre align at some point so ignore the cluster in the middle. The next step fixes that automatically anyways*

You can delete the box now.

#### Now select all of your letters and use the horizontal distribute centres function again.

[image: the result]

If you want to check that against the box, it looks like this.

[image: measuring against the box]

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some braintorture... i figured it out by creating a new document exactly 80 mm wide and just align all the letters equally.

Comment: Hey Pablo, good to see you solved your own problem. Could you please explain in a bit more detail, so later visitors may benefit from your solution? What tools and methods did you use? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a text box, either by dragging a box iwth type tool or convery a box to a textbox with type area tool.
2. Type your text into the box.
3. Open the paragraph styles palette and make a new paragraph style.

   1. Set the size of your font
   2. Set the *Indents and spacing → Alignment* to Full Justify